# MySQL Update if duplicate row

Tags: mysql

I have a table with duplicate rows. I want to update the rows before I delete them just to me sure that I delete the good ones.

The delete query is this and works:

```
DELETE FROM cscart_products 
WHERE updated_timestamp 
NOT IN (SELECT * 
    FROM (SELECT MAX(n.updated_timestamp) 
    FROM cscart_products n 
    GROUP BY n.product_code) x)
```

Example table:

```
product_code    product_type    status    updated_timestamp
DUSP1893        P               A         1551
DUSP1893        P               A         322
AH324444        P               A         555
AH324444        P               A         21332
```

Some products have the same product_code. I want to update those with a smaller updated_timestamp from status A to H.

Thanky you

Comment: Read this post three times now, still have not figured out what the actual question is. You just want to add an extra condition on the status?

Comment: I want for example to change the status from A to H at DUSP1893 where updated_timestamp is smalller. Same for AH324444.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get the rows with smaller timestamp and then update those records, like this:

```
UPDATE cscart_products
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT product_code pc, MIX(updated_timestamp) ts
  FROM cscart_products
  GROUP BY product_code
) t
ON cscart_products.product_code = t.pc 
AND cscart_products.updated_timestamp = t.ts
SET status = 'H'
```

Inner query will give you rows of product_code having smaller timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

You must do it on transaction.
1. Start transaction
2. Update
3. Delete
4. Commit transaction

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE cscart_products SET status="H" WHERE updated_timestamp<some_value AND product_code IN (code1,code2,....codeN);
DELETE FROM cscart_products WHERE status="H" AND product_code IN (code1,code2,....codeN);
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Why **must** OP do it in a transaction?

Answer (score 0):

It should not be more complicated than this:

```
-- mark the rows for which the updated_timestamp is smaller
-- than the maximum timestamp for that product_code
UPDATE cscart_products 
SET status = 'H'
WHERE updated_timestamp 
NOT IN (SELECT * 
    FROM (SELECT MAX(n.updated_timestamp) 
    FROM cscart_products n 
    GROUP BY n.product_code) x);

-- delete the marked rows (or don't, whatever you feel like)
DELETE FROM cscart_products 
WHERE status = 'H';
```

Answer (score 0):

To update smallest updated_timestamp that are duplicate in product_code, with status 'H'

```
UPDATE cscart_products SET status='H'
WHERE updated_timestamp IN
(SELECT * FROM(SELECT MIN(updated_timestamp) FROM cscart_products  
GROUP BY product_code HAVING COUNT(product_code)>1)  X);
```